# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer

Tags: django

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
   psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

how can i change this

i don't find the errors

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 43, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
    File "d:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
    File "d:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
    File "d:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
    File "F:/web_project/MxOnline\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
    File "F:/web_project/MxOnline\manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 535, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 124, in _alter_field
new_db_params, strict,
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 685, in _alter_field
params,
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
    File "F:\Evns\mxonline\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: "..operator does not exist: character varying >= integer .. You [..] *need to* add explicit type casts.."

Comment: Basically it's rejecting `"some text" >= 1234`. Make sure to compare the right columns with compatible column types; convert with explicit casts as required.

Comment: please share your code in the question. this problem can be solved by type casting if the logging has guided us properly. Then `int(string)>integer_value` can be the solution

Comment: @shourav  i just install django and xadmin

Comment: where did the error happen?? in which line? please post your full stacktrace

Comment: @shourav i have post

Comment: can you post the model code?? I think error in migrate